# Does this Null Pointer Exception post solve every NPE question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've noticed quite a bit of Null Pointer Exception questions in the Java tag lately. Almost every single one has been closed, saying it's a duplicate of this post

[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it?lq=1)

Even if the OP does not post anything in the line of "What is a NPE?"

I don't understand how it's an exact duplicate.

Can every NPE question really be solved by just looking at this post? Is it okay to slap this link in every NPE post?

Also, I don't frequent the meta much, so I don't really know how to tag my questions.

Comment: Dang I tried searching if this question has been asked or not.

Comment: Yeah, the "Related" questions sidebar is a lot more accurate than the question list suggested while you write.

Comment: "Lately": you must be new here.

Comment: Pretty much.  There is no solution for NREs except to not finger nulls, which is well covered in the canonical.  All solutions are the same--identify the null, and program around the fact that it can be null.

Comment: @Raedwald I am actually.